# jquery 1.10.2 - Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: select

Tags: jquery

I have two dropdowns in my page and I am setting the visibility of one according to the value of other as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (($("#response option:selected").val() == "A") || ($("#response option:selected").val() == 'B')) {
            $("#additional").show();
            $(document).scrollTo('#additional');
        }
        $('#response').change(function () {
            $("#response option:selected").val();
            if (($("#response option:selected").val() == "A") || ($("#response option:selected").val() == 'B')) {
                $("#additional").show();

            } else {
                $("#additional").hide();
            }
        });
    });
----------------------------------------------------------


<div id="response" class="col-lg-4"> 
<select>
<option value="">Please Select</option> 
<option value="A">A</option>
 <option value="B">B</option>
 <option value="C">C</option> 
</select> 
</div>
<div id="additional" style="display: block;"> 
<select><option value="00">Please Select </option></select> 
</div>
```

This is not working and I am getting a console error like "jquery 1.10.2 - Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: select" . What could be the issue?

Comment: [That works just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/vbuhag8d/1/), though using `val` on the `select` makes more sense. From the error message, you've clearly used `:select` rather than `:selected` somewhere. It's just a typo.

Comment: The error is pointing to the included js file -  jquery 1.10.2. But I couldn't figure out what is the issue.

Comment: It's not an error in jQuery. jQuery is throwing the error because you've used `:select` instead of `:selected` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

**just val and not option selected**

```
$('#response select').val()
```

Comment: But #response is the id of a div outside dropdown.

Comment: response is select id i guess?

Comment: <div id="response" class="col-lg-4">
                <select><option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
</select>
 </div><div id="additional" style="display: block;">
                    <select><option value="00">Please Select </option></select>
            </div>

Comment: @Anoopa: That would have been useful information to include in the question. It was perfectly reasonable for Akshay to assume that the `select` was the element with the ID `response`.

Comment: @Akshay :  It was working fine for me before. Now it started giving error like this. One more thing is it is still working in my local . Issue is there only when I publish it to production.

Answer (score 0):

`:selected` is a typo. You can use `:select` pseudo-selector instead, but I recommend using `val()`. Also, I recommend storing the context you are reusing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var responseSelect = $("#response select");
    var additional = $("#additional");
    if ((responseSelect.val() == "A") || (responseSelect.val() == 'B')) {
        additional.show();
        $(document).scrollTo(additional);
    }
    responseSelect.change(function () {
        var currentVal = $(this).val();
        if ((currentVal == "A") || (currentVal == 'B')) {
            additional.show();

        } else {
            additional.hide();
        }
    });
});
```